# Writing table from SQL query directly to other database in R

Tags: sql, r, bigdata, rodbc

So in a database ***Y*** I have a table ***X*** with more than 400 million observations. Then I have a *KEY.csv* file with IDs, that I want to use for filtering the data (small data set, ca. 50k unique IDs). If I had unlimited memory, I would do something like this:

```
require(RODBC)
require(dplyr)

db <- odbcConnect('Y',uid = "123",pwd  = '123')
df  <- sqlQuery(db,'SELECT * from X')
close(db) 
keys <- read.csv('KEY.csv')
df_final <- df %>% filter(ID %in% KEY$ID)
```

My issue is, that I don't have the rights to upload the KEY.csv file to the database ***Y*** and do the filtering there. Would it be somehow possible to do the filtering in the query, while referencing the file loaded in R memory? And then write this filtered ***X*** table directly to a database I have access? I think even after filtering it R might not be able to keep it in the memory.

I could also try to do this in Python, however don't have much experience in that language.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how many keys you have but maybe you can try to use the `build_sql()` function to use the keys inside the query.
I dont use RODBC, I think you should use odbc and DBI (https://db.rstudio.com).

```
library(dbplyr) # dbplyr not dplyr
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
# Get keys first
keys = read.csv('KEY.csv')
db = dbConnect('Y',uid = "123",pwd  = '123') # the name of function changes in odbc
# write your query (dbplyr)
sql_query = build_sql('SELECT * from X
                where X.key IN ', keys, con = db)
df = dbGetQuery(db,sql_query) # the name of function changes in odbc
```

Comment: I used following code:
`db2 <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),'Y',uid = "123",pwd  = '123')`

`df2 <- tbl(db2, in_schema('A', 'X')) %>% filter(ID %in% !!unique(KEY$ID)) 
` 
However, I have about 50 unique IDs in the KEY.csv, so even getting the number of rows is extremly slow. Is there aby other way to work with this dataset?

Comment: Maybe try with my code using the `build_sql()` function to filter inside the SQL query ?

Comment: my code does exactly the same, however in my comment (which I am not able to edit now), I wore that there are 50 unique IDs, instead of 50k (50 000). The table X has 473Mil rows and 16 columns and it is saved in the Postgresql database, if that helps anyone.

Comment: You should use a LEFT JOIN in the sql query then.

Comment: but I do not want to join any other data, just filter the observations that are not in the KEY.csv  out

Comment: LEFT JOIN can be used to filter data : https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-joins-where-vs-on/